# The absolute value of product function is convex?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove that the function define on $\mathbb R^2$ is convex.
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=|x_1x_2|+x_1^2+x_2^2
$$
I know I should try to compute hessian, but the term $|x_1x_2|$ makes it hard to do so. Is there any trick to do this problem? I am still want to use hessian but not to use the basic definition, i.e., take two points and try to compute the linear combination of those two points...

Thank you!

Comment: $$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\lvert x_1\rvert^2 + \lvert x_2\rvert^2 + (\lvert x_1\rvert + \lvert x_2\rvert)^2\bigr)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I am aware of this trick, but still how may I do derivative on this? or I just miss sth simple...

Comment: No need to differentiate. The sum of convex functions is convex, the square of a non-negative convex function is convex.

Comment: @DanielFischer Understand... yea, I missed sth very simple...